# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'terra_proto.terra'

Tags: python, terra

I have currently installed the terra_sdk==2.0.6 version because trying to use
Terra's older version the Terra 1.0, so that it's compatible with the chain-id columbus 5. How do I fix this?

```
from terra_sdk.client.lcd import LCDClient
terra = LCDClient(chain_id = "columbus-5", url="https://lcd.terra.dev")
```

```html
File ~/Terra /venvT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/terra_sdk/core/market/__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .msgs import MsgSwap, MsgSwapSend
      3 __all__ = ["MsgSwap", "MsgSwapSend"]

File ~/Terra /venvT/lib/python3.9/site-packages/terra_sdk/core/market/msgs.py:6, in <module>
      3 from __future__ import annotations
      5 import attr
----> 6 from terra_proto.terra.market.v1beta1 import MsgSwap as MsgSwap_pb
      7 from terra_proto.terra.market.v1beta1 import MsgSwapSend as MsgSwapSend_pb
      9 from terra_sdk.core import AccAddress, Coin

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'terra_proto.terra'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: pip install terra-proto==1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this?

> Terra SDK uses Poetry to manage dependencies. To get set up with all
> the required dependencies, run:

```
    $ pip install poetry
    $ poetry install
```

from documentation https://github.com/terra-money/terra.py/tree/v2.0.6#dependencies

`terra-proto` seems to be in the list of dependencies